# Hive with space delimited values

Tags: hive

I'm new to hive and I want to use it on data that is space delimited. Is there a pre-existing way to do it so that it groups together things that are in quotes ("")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is as told by Tariq above.
And another is defining **regular expressions**.

You can **RegexSerDe class** of Hive for defining  regex as per your need.
Lets look at the example :

For Apache access log, there is sample data in the following form :

```
10.243.31.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:16:38:07 +0530] "POST /Haas/controller/main.php HTTP/1.1" 200 26 "http://10.232.5.169:81/Haas/view/dashboard.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"
10.243.31.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:16:38:07 +0530] "POST /Haas/controller/main.php HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "http://10.232.5.169:81/Haas/view/dashboard.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"
10.243.31.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:16:38:13 +0530] "POST /Haas/controller/main.php HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "http://10.232.5.169:81/Haas/view/dashboard.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"
```

Now we want to define the regex for it, and store this data into hive table. 
So Hive table schema would be:

```
CREATE TABLE apache_log(
  host STRING,
  identity STRING,
  user STRING,
  time STRING,
  request STRING,
  status STRING,
  size STRING,
  referer STRING,
  agent STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)(?: ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\"))?",
  "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

For more reference refer [GettingStarted#DDL_Operations](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#DDL_Operations)

Comment: I ended up using this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the last part of your question. Loading space separated data is same as loading any other character delimited data :

> CREATE TABLE demo(f1 datatype, ..., fn datatype) ROW
>   FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';

Comment: is there any way to specify that things inside "" are one block even though they are space separated